# Is cannabis curing stomach and bowel diseases considered incurable by modern medecine?

Tags: medical-science, natural-remedies

The website green rush daily [makes the claim](https://www.greenrushdaily.com/2017/02/17/cannabis-curing-stomach-bowel-diseases-considered-incurable-modern-medicine/)

> CANNABIS IS CURING STOMACH AND BOWEL DISEASES CONSIDERED INCURABLE BY
>   MODERN MEDICINE

And then

> studies and empirical evidence show that cannabis can cure several
>   stomach and bowel diseases considered incurable by modern medicine.
>   New research suggests that cannabis could be the cure for Crohn’s and
>   other bowel diseases.

When looking through the article it refers to science but that does not mean its represented properly. Is it?

Answer (score 8):

There is only [one paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3631143/) referenced in the article. That paper describes an increase in cannabinoid receptors in the gut tissue of people suffering from celiac disease, and suggests that reducing the activity of those receptors might help. This is one small piece of a huge biochemical jigsaw puzzle. The scientists did not experiment with cannabinoids on the biopsies that they took, and do not suggest that this might be worth trying. In short, this research has nothing to do with whether cannabis can treat (never mind "cure") celiac disease.

The rest of the links in the article are to

- Previous articles at the same site, which are no better than this one.
- Individual anecdotes from people who saw an improvement in their condition after trying cannabis. Anecdotal evidence is the lowest form of evidence; if many such anecdotes are collected then it can be a pointer for some proper research, but individual anecdotes can simply be a combination of co-incidence and cherry-picking.

In conclusion, the article offers no evidence to support its headline.